# Shader blending decal system for blender

Tags: materials

Is there any way, natively or by using a plugin that decals can be created which can be projected onto the target mesh which blend the shaders of decal and target? This is possible in video game engines but would be really useful for use in creating dynamic environments for rendering. Many thanks, Danny.

Ps. i am not personally concerned with the matching the 2 meshes, its getting the shaders to blend which i am interested in.

Comment: I believe DecalMachine (not free) can be used for something to this effect. You can use it to place decals in a non-committal way and I THINK there's functionality to bake them into the material/texture. See if it does what you need: https://machin3.io/DECALmachine/docs/

Comment: thanks that looks like it might be a good solution, one would have thought that there would be a free method out there somewhere though...